# Flash catalyst and Flash Builder round tripping for complex applications

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder, flashcatalyst, roundtrip

Can anyone give me some tips for round tripping between flash catalyst and flash builder for complex applications that uses components not supported in flash catalyst?

Let's say I have built my design in flash catalyst and have implemented transitions and lots of animations.

How can I bring this into flash builder and add a calendar component (which is unsurpported in flash catalyst)?

Since the design in flash catalyst represents the main application, I don't think it would be suitable to turn it into a component. The calendar component would need to sit in the main application.

Any suggestions appreciated :)

**EDIT:** I am using flash builder 4.5.1 and catalyst cs 5.5

Comment: Voted to close because this question is too broad.  What have you tried? Which version of Flash Builder/Catalyst? What issues have you seen with custom components?

Comment: I have edited the op to show the versions of builder/catalyst. I am not sure what you meant by issues with custom components. Simply put, I would like to integrate catalyst into my workflow. However, the application needs to use unsupported components such as the "DateChooser (calendar)" component. I would like to animate the component moving into place in catalyst for example. however, importing the fxp from catalyst into builder creates a "catalyst compatible project", which means I am not even able to add "non-compatible" components into the application.